# Non-deductible contribution amounts are always $0

Tags: civievent, contributions

Create an event with a price set which contains two price fields. One price field contains items of financial type "Event Fee" which is defined as non-deductible. The other price field contains items of financial type "Donation" which is defined as deductible.

The Financial Type of the Event, specified on the Fees page, is Donation (although setting it to Event does not change the result).

When a participant registers and selects for example a $30 Event Fee option and a $100 Donation option, a contribution is created which shows the two line items with a net amount of $130 as expected. The non-deductible amount, however, is shown as $0, rather than $30 as I would have expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

I'm running 4.6.14 and confirmed the same issue exists on the demo site (4.7.5).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old ticket; just wanted to add a note that I'm 99% sure we fixed this in 4.6 and 4.7 - and also added a PHP Unit test for it - so that makes it harder to break in future. I've not had any of our client reporting this issue anymore - however if you still experience this in a later version of either 4.6 or 4.7 - please do let us know.

Found the PRs: 
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6895
https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6896

**UPDATE:** 1% it is! I just quickly tried to reproduce your exact scenario - and sigh... it is still an issue in 4.7.18 - will get this fixed. Slightly different pathway than the one we fixed above. In the screenshot below - non-deductible should be $0.30

[image]

Comment: Hey @BobS - just looping back to this [sorry it took me some time to do so] - I did have a good look and this is potentially fixable in 4.6 - however in 4.7 this will be significantly more difficult due to a new 'feature' - which a) is not working and b) ignores the is Deductible? setting on the Financial Type completely; I help maintain the CDN TaxReceipts Extension - and this non-deductible field is very important to ensure accurate TaxReceipts calculations - we'll implement a fix there - an (ad-hoc) reconciliation/fix task for non-deductible amounts;  What Country are you in Bob?

Answer (score 0):

Please create an issue on JIRA and assign it to me so I can have my staff look into this.

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use the API csv Import to update the non_deductible_amount column of the civicrm_contributions table.