# Add 'Non-deductible amount' to Contribution Receipt template

Tags: smarty

I am trying to add the non-deductible amount to my Automatic Contribution receipt but it is not printing the value. Any tips? I am using Civicrm 4.6.19 with Drupal 7

```
  <tr>
    <td {$labelStyle}>
      {ts}Non-deductible Amount{/ts}
    </td>
    <td {$valueStyle}>
      {$nonDeductAmount|crmMoney:$currency}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug that does not fill the civicrm_contribution table non-deductible_amount column. Until that is fixed this will continue not printing a value. For now you can use the API csv Import to update that column for existing donations.

There is another thread started about this. [Non-deductible contribution amounts are always $0](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10940/non-deductible-contribution-amounts-are-always-0)

Comment: Iowa Boy, do you have a link to that bug?

Comment: Here is the one for the 4.6 in this thread. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6895

Comment: Gee, I just resurrected a 2-year old thread. Derp de derp.